# Many links with same jquery animation, how to organize them better?

Tags: jquery, html, slidetoggle

I have an question about jQuery - I'm working on big system's menu simulation, so others can play with that and decide, how it should be better organized - usability and user experience stuff.

Menu is multilevel and every part must be draggable - so it's important (I guess) to stay all parts in same page. 
But this not what I want to ask actually. I have submenu's menu, so it opens using slideToggle() class by clicking on the menu link.

```
<script>
  $( "#terms" ).click(function() {
   $( "#1" ).slideToggle( "slow" );
  });
 $( "#tc" ).click(function() {
   $( "#tc-2" ).slideToggle( "slow" );
  });
</script>
```

I have a lot of that kind of links, so I don't want to write code for every link, I want to create something like

```
<script>
  $( "a" ).click(function() {
   $( "#href" ).slideToggle( "slow" );
  });
</script>
```

So by clicking on the link it opens only this div, which have same id, as link href.

Sorry for lame question, I really don't know how to explain google what  I want.

Comment: data-reference not work in where browser not support html5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one way is to use HTML5 data attribute..add reference id of the toggle element to it... add same class to all elements and use

```
 $( ".elementClass" ).click(function() {
    $('#'+ $(this).data('reference')).slideToggle( "slow" );
 });
```

example HTML

```
<div id="terms" class="elementClass" data-reference="1"></div>
<div id="1"></div>
<div id="tc" class="elementClass" data-reference="tc-2"></div>
<div id="tc-2"></div>
```

note: it is best to avoid numeric values as ids. use string.

Answer (score 0):

**data-reference not work in where browser not support html5** so used this code

```
     $( ".elementClass" ).click(function() {
        $('#'+ $(this).attr('id')+'-div').slideToggle( "slow" );
     });

example HTML

    <div id="terms-1" class="elementClass"></div>
    <div id="terms-1-div"></div>
    <div id="tc-2" class="elementClass"></div>
    <div id="tc-2-div"></div>
```

Comment: Since it is testing system - I don't think supporting all browsers is important here. But it may be useful in some real projects. So thank you for your solution:)